# Jitbit macro recorder alternative for Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, software-recommendation

I'm used to JitBit Macro Recorder on Windows.

The most important feature that I'm looking for is the `if pixel by color X found at coordinates` condition. Is there such a macro recorder for Ubuntu?

My goal is to automate long repetitive tasks.